# Image segmentation using imagemagick

Tags: java, imagemagick, segment

I am new to the Imagemagick but am trying to do the segmentation for an image i.e., when I gave an image of two persons to segmentation code then the output image should come up with dotted line on the persons edge i.e., segment recognition.
I already tried with the -segment command, but unable to execute the command.

can any one help me by providing the way to solve the segmentation for an image.

thanks in advance,
Jhon

Answer (score 1):

Image segmentation is a very sophisticated task. Simple segmentation by color or any other primitive metrics is only possible in very controlled scenarios.

Anders already suggested taking a look into OpenCV - if you are really interesd in this topic, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) may help to get a start.
-> Color based segmentation quick guide via [OpenCV](http://bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/60-2-color-based-object-segmentation) (this code is C, but the java library should be almost the same)
-> Simple edge detection may be done by the prominent *Canny Edge Detector*

For testing, matlab would be a good tool to get fast results.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly the ImageMagick `segment` command will segment an image based on some measure and certain fuzziness and segment size parameters. You'll end up with samecolored segments. It sounds like you really want to do *edge detection* on the image/persons?

In general, segmentation is one of the harder problems in computer vision, and perhaps ImageMagick isn't the best tool for this - may I suggest to have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) instead.

Cheers,